# Objective C - Accessors ie Getters/Setters

Tags: objective-c

I Have read the already posted questions extensively and can't quite find the answer I'm looking for.

I fully understand the concept of using the `@syntesize` directive to create getter and setter methods (i.e. if i had `@property int width` and `@synthesize width`, I am inadvertently creating a getter method of `width` and a setter method of `setWidth:`).

However, when I am not using the `@synthesize` directive but am declaring instance variables in the `@implementation` section that are objects, I do not fully understand how the accessor methods work. This is what I do not understand about the following code:

1)  in `main` where it says:

```
NSLog(@"Origin at (%i, %i)", myRect.origin1.x, myRect.origin1.y);
```

It appears to me as if it would be calling the `[[myRect origin1] x]` method which would first determine that `[myRect origin1]` returns `origin` and would then immediately call `[origin x]` as a result (and then do the same for `y`).  Now, what throws me off is the fact that if I were to change the name of the getter method

```
-(XYpoint *) origin1;
```

contained within Rectangle.h to

```
-(XYpoint *) origin2;
```

the program gets tons of errors and ceases to compile.  Note: I also changed the name of this method everywhere it is referenced including changing the preceding code in main to

```
NSLog(@"Origin at (%i, %i)", myRect.origin2.x, myRect.origin2.y);
```

However if I also change the name of the setter method from:

```
-(void) setOrigin1: (XYpoint *) pt
```

to:

```
-(void) setOrigin2: (XYpoint *) pt
```

then everything works as it did before.  It seems to me it only works correctly when my getter and setter are both named in the `x` `setX` naming convention.  I supposed this is mainly what I need explained:

A)  If I create an instance variable that happens to be an object (like 'origin' in this case) must I create getter and setter methods for it?

B)  Can I create a getter method but not a setter method or vice versa

C)  Is it mandatory that if I do create both a getter and setter method for 'origin' that they both be named in the `x` `setX` manner.  In this case as `-(XYpoint *) origin1` and `-(void) setOrigin1: (XYpoint *) pt`.  As in if I change the name of the getter I must change the name of the setter accordingly?

Here is all of the code:

Rectangle.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@class XYpoint;

@interface Rectangle : NSObject

@property int width, height;

-(XYpoint *) origin1;
-(void) setOrigin1: (XYpoint *) pt;
-(void) setWidth: (int) w andHeight: (int) h;
-(int) area;
-(int) perimeter;

@end
```

Rectangle.m:

```
#import "Rectangle.h"

@implementation Rectangle
{
    XYpoint *origin;
}

@synthesize  width, height;

-(void) setWidth:(int) w andHeight:(int)h
{
    width = w;
    height = h;
}


-(void) setOrigin1: (XYpoint *) pt
{
    origin = pt;
}

-(int) area
{
    return width * height;
}

-(int) perimeter
{
    return (width + height) * 2;
}

-(XYpoint *) origin1
{
    return origin;
}

@end
```

XYpoint.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface XYpoint : NSObject

@property int x, y;

-(void) setX: (int) xVal andY: (int) yVal;
@end
```

XYpoint.m:

```
#import "XYpoint.h"

@implementation XYpoint

@synthesize x,y;

-(void) setX: (int) xVal andY: (int) yVal
{
    x = xVal;
    y = yVal;
}
@end
```

main.m:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Rectangle.h"
#import "XYpoint.h"

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {
        Rectangle *myRect = [[Rectangle alloc] init];
        XYpoint *myPoint = [[XYpoint alloc] init];

        [myPoint setX: 100 andY: 200];
        [myRect setWidth: 5 andHeight:8];
        myRect.origin1 = myPoint;
        NSLog(@"Rectangle w = %i, h = %i", myRect.width, myRect.height);
        NSLog(@"Origin at (%i, %i)", myRect.origin1.x, myRect.origin1.y);
        NSLog(@"Area = %i, Perimeter = %i", [myRect area], [myRect perimeter]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The dot notation is really just shorthand for the accessor calls. Since myRect.origin2 could equate to [myRect origin2] OR [myRect setOrigin2], depending on context, both of those accessors need to be defined in order to use the dot notation. Regardless, you should really be declaring instance variables as properties, as in Jakob's answer.

Comment: Thank you! That is exactly my problem.  Changing my getter (or setter) from setOrigin1 to setOrigin2 would then mean that when myRect.origin1 is called it essentially needs both a getter/setter named accordingly.  And since I changed setOrigin1 to setOrigin2 there is no longer both a getter and setter.  Even if I never use it the compiler requires it.  At least I believe thats what you mean.  If so, it makes sense to me now.  Though I don't know how to give you a "correct" answer since its just listed as a comment

Comment: This is wrong. You don't need both accessors. If you define `-(int)foo;` in your header file, you can use `int x = myObj.foo;`. On the other hand, if you define `-(void)setBar:(int)anInt;` in the header file, you can use `myObj.bar = 15;`. Getters and setters are independent.

Comment: OK, hmm strange then.  Because if you were to copy/paste my code and run it (I'm not suggesting to though lol) you would see that as soon as you change the getter "-(XYpoint *) origin1" to "-(XYpoint *) origin2" (and change every reference to it also) it gets errors.  What the guy above said though is that if you reference it in dot notation as myRect.origin1 then I have to have a getter/setter combo named "origin1" and "setOrigin1" since it could be referring to either of them.  And by changing the name of one of mine I no have a getter/setter combo named origin1/setOrigin1.  Confusing I know

Comment: You are using the dot notation twice: once you write `myRect.origin1 = myPoint`, (here you use the setter), and then in the NSLog line, you use the getter. If you change the name of the getter to origin2, you must only change the NSLog line.

Comment: Let me rephrase what isn't working:  When I change the actual name for my getter from `-(XYpoint *) origin1` to `-(XYpoint *) origin2` in both the interface & implementation, the only other spots I am changing it is in `main` on the line `NSLog(@"Origin at (%i, %i)", myRect.origin1.x, myRect.origin1.y);` where I change it to `NSLog(@"Origin at (%i, %i)", myRect.origin2.x, myRect.origin2.y);`  I am aware that the `myRect.origin1 = myPoint` refers to the setter method `-(void) setOrigin1: (XYpoint *) pt` hence I have not changed it.  Still, I get an error.

Comment: That's odd. I tried your code, and for me that worked (but I copied it all into one file, maybe that changed something?)

Comment: do you mean you copied my code, and then made the changes to from origin1 to origin2 where i mentioned above??? If so is it possible to copy/paste and send me it?  I am new on this forum and don't know if you can PM stuff like that

Comment: Here's the code I tried: http://pastebin.com/sagRsnQK it worked perfectly when compiled with `clang -framework Foundation test.m`

Comment: I just ran what you sent and get errors (I actually moved main to the end -- i prefer it that way but same errors regardless).  Here is a [screenshot](http://postimage.org/image/utwtoykk3/) of them in case you may know what they mean.  I could send you my actual project file if you wanted but I don't want to take up your whole day really with my problem.

Comment: I haven't seen these errors before. I'm intrigued. Feel free to contact me via email (jabakobob at gmail com). Anyway, check if you are on the latest version of XCode, maybe it is a bug in clang. (if you got XCode from the Mac App Store, try running the "Install Xcode" application after updates)

Comment: I sent it to you.  Thank you so much.  Being new to this forum it's great to see people so willing to help and I hope I can get to a point where I can reciprocate by helping new users later on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After discussion via email, we found out that the issue actually seems to be a bug in clang. Consider the following mini program:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface TestObject : NSObject
-(void)setIdVar:(id)someId;
@end

@implementation TestObject
-(void)setIdVar:(id)someId;
{
    NSLog(@"-setIdVar called with argument: %@", someId);
}
@end

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        TestObject *testObj = [[TestObject alloc] init];
        testObj.idVar = @"test";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Obviously, we expect this program to run and output `-setIdVar called with argument: test`. And that's exactly what happens when you compile it without ARC (e.g.. using `clang -framework Foundation main.m`).

But if we compile it with ARC, clang crashes. (`clang -framework Foundation -fobjc-arc main.m`)

Funny thing is, this crash doesn't happen when using setters for non-object types (eg. int) or when a getter is defined.

Answer (score 5):

> A) If I create an instance variable that happens to be an object (like
>   'origin' in this case) must I create getter and setter methods for it?

No. If you declare a property, you'll need to either provide your own accessors or use the @synthesize directive to create them. But you can have all the instance variables you like without having accessors for them.

> B) Can I create a getter method but not a setter method or vice versa

Yes, you can provide just the getter if you declare your property `readonly`.

> C) Is it mandatory that if I do create both a getter and setter method
>   for 'origin' that they both be named in the x setX manner. In this
>   case as -(XYpoint *) origin1 and -(void) setOrigin1: (XYpoint *) pt.
>   As in if I change the name of the getter I must change the name of the
>   setter accordingly?

You can provide your own names for the accessors, but you should stick with the usual convention if you want your class to be key value coding compliant for the property in question:

```
@property (getter=isBar, setter=setBar) int bar;
```

Answer (score 3):

You most likely forgot to change the method names in the header or implementation files. It's perfectly valid to have read-only properties (without setter methods).

The best practice if you have an object property that you want to access using the dot-notation (ie. `myRect.origin1`), is to make sure you define the corresponding property in the header file, ie. include a line such as:

```
@property(readonly) XYPoint *origin1; // for read only properties
@property(retain) XYPoint *origin1; // for read/write properties
```

Use them even if you don't use `@synthesize`, and use them instead of the normal method declarations in the header file. These lines don't actually create getters and setters, they just inform the compiler that your class has these properties. The compiler will then expect getters (and setters if you don't use readonly) named `-origin1` and `-setOrigin1`. The names of the setters/getters are important (see Apple's Documentation on Key-Value Coding for details)

You should also be aware of Cocoa's memory management guidelines: Unless you are using Automatic reference counting, your Rectangle class is responsible for retaining or copying the XYPoint object in the setter. *[EDIT]: I just realised that you are obviously using ARC since you use the `@autoreleasepool` syntax.*

Comment: I have changed the names in the header file as well as the implementation file.  Still when my getter and setter methods aren't manually named "origin1" and "setOrigin1" but "origin1" and "setOrigin2" I get tons of errors.  But then when I change "setOrigin2" back to "setOrigin1" it all works again.... sorry if I am a little confusing, I am new here.

Comment: This is really what is baffling me:  Why does my program get all kinds of errors if I change the name of the setOrigin1 setter method (and also change its name anywhere else it is referenced/used).  To me it seems like it is getting errors since it is no longer named in conjunction with the origin1 getter method.

Comment: It really sounds like a typo somewhere to me. Without seeing the exact warnings and source files, it's difficult to analyse what went wrong. The problem with using the dot-notation to access properties is that the compiler must be absolutely sure what the getters/setters are named. The best way to ensure that is to declare this properties in the header file using the `@property id foo;` syntax rather than declaring the methods `-(id)foo;` and `-(void)setFoo:(id)aFoo;` and hoping the compiler figures out these are properties.

Comment: I think I figured out the solution from a comment posted about.  Thank you very much though.  I know it is sometimes hard to read through all of that without actually running it.  It's highly unlikely to be a typo though as I copied and pasted it from a code that compiled correctly.  I will heed your advice though about trying to avoid declaring instance variables in the [@implementation] section and declaring them as [@property] instead and [@sythesize]-ing their accessors.

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. Methods, properties and instance variables are declared in the `@interface` section in the header file (someClass.h). The actual code goes into the `@implementation` section in someClass.m. You should use `@property`-style declarations for properties regardless wheter you use `@synthesize` or not.